# Always returning error message in simple login instead of success message

Tags: java, android, string

Hello my simple application is always returning error message instead of success message.

**RegisterActivity.class**

```
   Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra ( "user", username.getText().toString() );
            intent.putExtra ( "pass", password.getText().toString() );

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Submit, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
```

**LoginActivity.class**

```
private EditText username,password;
private Button ok,clear;


//String Array
String LoginSucc = "Login Success";
String LoginFailed= "Login Failed";
String ClearFields = "Text Fields Cleared";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    username = findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    password = findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

    ok = findViewById(R.id.Ok);
    clear = findViewById(R.id.Clear);


    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Bundle bb;
            bb=getIntent().getExtras();

            if(username.equals(bb.getString("user"))&& password.equals(bb.getString("pass")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LoginSucc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LoginFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Always returning `LoginFailed` Message even i put correct Login Info.

Comment: can you post your complete login activity?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque done! thank you

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque Edit I change MainActivity.class to LoginActivity.class to be more specific

Comment: after bb.getIntent().getExtras() just do a Log.e() and see if you are getting user and pass right before entering the if statment

Comment: checkout my answer @neiltan :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to do this:

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             String userName = username.getText().toString();
             String passWord = password.getText().toString();
            Bundle bb;
            bb=getIntent().getExtras();

            if(userName.equals(bb.getString("user"))&& passWord.equals(bb.getString("pass")))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LoginSucc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), LoginFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    })
```

;

Comment: as Levi says, you need to get the values inside your editText before compare it with the current pass and user passed by the putextras

Comment: Oh Thank you! So much A life savior ! ill mark your answer in 3min "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes"

Comment: glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you forgot to create a Bundle object in the first activity.

RegisterActivity.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),LoginActivity.class);
       String username = username.getText().toString();
       String password = password.getText().toString();

       Bundle bb = new Bundle();
       bb.putString("user", username);
       bb.putString("pass", password);

       intent.putExtras(bb);

       startActivity(intent);
```

LoginActivity.class

```
 private Bundle bb;
...
    bb = intent.getExtras(); 
    String getUsername = extras.getString("user");
    String getPassword = extras.getString("pass");
```